# Find the frequency of unique names

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I have subfolders of compressed csv `(.csv.gz)` files containing usernames and I'm trying to find the frequency of usernames.

The following bash pipeline gives me top users.

`for subfolder in folder; do gunzip -rc $subfolder | cut -d, -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head; done`

However, it is very slow when I have many large files in the subfolders. Is there a more efficient bash script for this purpose?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're looping calling `gunzip -rc` one "subfolder" at a time instead of doing `gunzip -rc folder` without a loop? Also - "folder" is a Windows term, in Unix there are "directories" and "files".

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the heads up. Sometimes sorting many sorted files is faster than sorting a huge unsorted file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the number of unique users, you could let `awk` do the heavylifting (counting repeated entries as they are read, without sorting) and then sort the result. It should go faster (but you still have to decompress everything and that takes sometime):

```
$ for subfolder in folder; do gunzip -rc $subfolder | awk -F, '{l[$1]++} END {for (i in l) {print l[i],i}}' | sort -rn | head;done
```

As a reference, you cannot make it run faster than:

```
$ for subfolder in folder; do gunzip -rc $subfolder > /dev/null;done
```

Comment: Thanks. `awk` makes it 5x faster and I believe the speedup is more than 5 for larger data sets.

Comment: @kiasari you are welcome. Please consider marking the answer as accepted if that is the case so that other people can profit from it in a similar situation.